# Using WebAPI for Token based Authentication to authenticate MVC and Mobile App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

What I am trying to do is use WebAPI to authenticate both an MVC application and a mobile app using Token based auth.  I currently have the MVC application authenticating with the database directly using the standard .NET SignInManager code the VS generates.  I have my WebAPI in a different project and will reside in a different website.

I have the mobile app using the API for token based auth.  What I am trying to do now is move the MVC app to use this same auth.  I am hoping to using the SignInManager as I am now and just change the underlying auth location to the API using tokens.  I am doing this to authenticate the user in the MVC application and also using the token from the API to secure the API.

I not sure that this is a good idea or what the best way to accomplish this is.  It may be a bad idea. Maybe I should merge the API and MVC applications into the same project?  Any feedback or ideas would be great.

If this does not make sense, please let me know.

Comment: At a high level, your problem seems to be this that you have multiple clients and a single authorization system.

To that end, you could either create an Identity Server (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) or use Azure Identity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/understand-azure-identity-solutions). If you want to look outside the Microsoft ecosystem, Amazon's AWS Cognito works well (https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a Web Api is the possibility to use a Service with multiple clients, i.e. an Angular Web App a Xamarin Mobile App and a Console App, all of them consuming the services of the API using the same Auth Method, usually Token based, conceptually that is the idea.

Now in your scenario you created a MVC Web App and then a Mobile App but for the mobile app you created also a Web Api, so basically you have two places where you put your Business Logic.

What I would recommend is to move and centralize everything in your Web Api and use that Auth only so in your MVC client project you just store your token as you do in your mobile App.

Comment: I am actually using the API for the business logic for web and mobile.  The web app is just a different front end as the mobile apps are.  What I was hoping to do was to use the token based auth that is working from Mobile to API in the web app.  I am not sure how to accomplish this in an automated fashion like when I have web app auth on its own against the same DB.  Does this make sense?  One Auth point of WebAPI for MVC and Mobile is the goal.